# Recovery a table in MySQL but it [Err] 1030 - Got error -1 from storage engine

Tags: windows, mysql5.5

I have a MySQL with InnoDB engine on a legacy Windows, MySQL version is really old is 5.5,I have a table is really big like 90Gigabytes, it disrupted its MySQL database  ,when the restful API read this table, the whole MYSQL service is downed,that's why I moved the damaged table .ibd file to out of MySQL data folder, then MySQL works fine, I tried to recovery this table in a test enviroment,
I tried

```
DROP TABLE mydb.your_table_name;
ALTER TABLE mydb.your_table_name DISCARD TABLESPACE;
ALTER TABLE mydb.your_table_name IMPORT TABLESPACE;
CHECK TABLE mydb.your_table_name;
```

then i got

```
[Err] 1030 - Got error -1 from storage engine
[SQL]alter table tmp_md_inv_03 discard tablespace
```

it looks like impossible to repair this table, any idea how to repair this table?